# How to interact with list of contents of a server directory using JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a simple code like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Directories Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Directories</h1>
<ul>
<%
String root="c:/";
java.io.File file;
java.io.File dir = new java.io.File(root);

String[] list = dir.list();

if (list.length > 0) {

for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  file = new java.io.File(root + list[i]);
  if (file.isDirectory()) {
  %>
  <li><a href="/<%=list[i]%>" target="_top"><%=list[i]%></a><br>
  <%
     }
  if (file.isFile()) {
      %>
      <li><a href="/<%=list[i]%>" target="_top"><%=list[i]%></a><br>
      <%
    }
  }
}
%>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:
[image: Output of code]
How I can interact with folder or file by clicking on its link? I mean - open folder or make some action with file? What I need to change? I understand that it has to handle clicking on links but do not understand how to do it. What I need to google?

Comment: If you want to add some "dynamic behaviour", you have to put some JavaScript in it. With JS, you can add event when you click on a link and a lot more :) If your app is simple, may be something like JQuery will be enough, if you want something complex, look at frameworks like Angular, React, etc...

And nothing related, but, that's a bad way to put Java directly in your JSP. So, i don't know your goal but take a look at the MVC pattern.

Comment: I know about MVC, but I have no choise.

Comment: IMHO, this is too broad for a SO question. Because an complete answer would have to deal with: how to process requests (and request parameters) in a JSP, how to encode special characters in a link, how to recursively walk in the server file system, how to keep the context of the current directory (session or request parameter). And as vincent already told you, it is better to put the java code in a servlet that will forward to a JSP that only deals with rendering the page

Comment: _I have no choise_ - if this means you have no other choice than putting your code directly into JSP (so you cannot use even some helper classes), then I can only say you should run away from such job.